# Can't use ARG in docker multistage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to use ARGS in the docker build process multistage.

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY=example.com/docker
FROM $DOCKER_REGISTRY/openjdk8:latest AS installer 
ARG APP_VERSION=6.3.0.78 
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY 
ARG REPO_TYPE=snapshot 
ARG DB_VERSION=12.2.0.11-ee
ARG DB_TYPE=oracle ARG PASSWORD

ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY 
ARG DB_VERSION 
ARG DB_TYPE
FROM ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DB_TYPE}/database:${DB_VERSION} 
ARG DB_VERSION 
ARG DB_TYPE
ARG PASSWORD
RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle/script
COPY --from=installer /opt/installer/target_script/* /opt/oracle/scripts/
```

Whenever it gets the second FROM step in the docker file it fails with the error `invalid reference format` since it won't recognize the syntax for getting the image.

My assumption is that it doesn't know to handle `ARG` in a multistage docker build.

Comment: You should renew ARG in each stage.

Comment: isn't that what I'm doing? can you have a look? the problem is with the second "FROM". I am trying to double call the same ARG as in the first stage

Comment: You have `DOCKER_REGISTRY` as a global. Why are you calling again?

Comment: I didn't know the usage of the scope of a global variable in docker multistage. and found some answered in the web naming to call the ARG again. As mentioned here above also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARG's are scoped. Before the first FROM line they are global and available in the FROM lines only. Within each stage, they are scoped until the end of that stage. So you need:

```
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY=example.com/docker
# move the DB_VERSION and DB_TYPE above the first FROM line
ARG DB_VERSION 
ARG DB_TYPE
FROM $DOCKER_REGISTRY/openjdk8:latest AS installer 

# none of these args seem to do anything, unless you have
# ONBUILD steps that depend on them in your openjdk image
ARG APP_VERSION=6.3.0.78 
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY 
ARG REPO_TYPE=snapshot 
ARG DB_VERSION=12.2.0.11-ee
ARG DB_TYPE=oracle ARG PASSWORD

FROM ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DB_TYPE}/database:${DB_VERSION} 

# none of these args are used either
ARG DB_VERSION 
ARG DB_TYPE
ARG PASSWORD

RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle/script
COPY --from=installer /opt/installer/target_script/* /opt/oracle/scripts/
```

Comment: How would you use the PASSWORD arg to pass to RUN command in this case? Since the password is not something I would like to be stored as env nor be visible in docker inspect command.

Comment: @MickeyHovel what is the password needed for during the build? That's not something you want to inject into the image in most situations, you would inject that at runtime, allowing the image to be used in different environments, and avoiding the password saved in any image layers/config. At runtime, on a single node as a read-only config file, in swarm or k8s with secrets, or even better with a KMS or Hashicorp's Vault.

Comment: The use case is as follows: the developer should be able to start a DB with the right schemas and migration. In order to have the right schemas we need to run some DB scripts. In order to run the DB script we need to connect the DB with the user name pass. One of the options is to run the DB scripts when deploying the pod as init container and so, but wanted to have a quick deployable DB container

Comment: @MickeyHovel a separate init container or entrypoint script to initialize a new DB is best. Another option is to hard code a build time DB password and then reset that to an injected run time password. However, that increases build complexity, bloats the image, and often has issues when used with volumes.

Comment: agreed that the best is to have it with entrypoint or init container when running in k8s. at the same time, I'll mention again the need of fast DB run (it's a developer-oriented environment and lots of scripts to execute)